# Recoverable error with dukt video

Tags: plugin-duktvideos, plugin-duktoauth

I have upgraded to Oauth (0.9.65) and Videos (1.0.23) but i'm getting an 'Recoverable error' when trying to edit a piece of content;

```
Argument 1 passed to Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::addClassMap() must be an array, integer given, called in /craft/plugins/videos/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 38 and defined

/craft/app/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(88)

public function addClassMap(array $classMap)
```

I wondered if anyone else has had this issue? I have tried re-uploading both plugins but the only way around at the moment is to disable the Videos plugin.

Comment: Hey, I've been unable to reproduce this error on a clean install. I also tried different versions of PHP without luck. Can you please double check that you have uploaded all files otherwise send me your Craft version and server details at support@dukt.net. Thank you

Comment: Wondering if you got this fixed? I have got a similar error http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9007/internal-server-error-with-dukt-video