# Internal server error with Dukt video

Tags: plugin-duktvideos

My site is working fine with dukt videos on local and staging but I am getting an error on any page with a dukt video field. Error is on the front end and the dashboard.

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> Argument 1 passed to Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::addClassMap() must be of the type array, integer given, called in /homepages/15/d322782150/htdocs/nailcote-craft/craft/plugins/videos/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 38 and defined

I've emailed support directly but in the meantime if anyone has come across this I would be glad of the help.

Comment: Seems rather strange. Would you be able to check what `$classMap` is set to? Maybe try a `var_dump($classMap)` after line 36 in autoload_real.php. Oh - and what does your `autoload_classmap.php` look like?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. I downloaded fresh copies of OAuth and Video plug-ins. Re-uploaded to server and it's all working.

I guess something got missed or corrupted in the initial upload.